# What version does the Perl interpreter use by default?

Tags: perl

I wrote a simple script using `given`/`when` to try out this feature, but I kept getting compilation errors. Eventually, I included `use 5.010_001;` at the top of the script, thinking maybe my Perl version is too old to use `given`/`when`. It worked.

I then printed my Perl version with `$]` and used it instead: `use 5.018_002;`, which also worked. Why isn't Perl using the features from the latest installed version by default?

Comment: "What version does the Perl interpreter use by default?" Whatever you specify in your shebang, or whatever comes first in your PATH, depending on how you invoke the script. What you're really asking about is what *features* are enabled by default; see [`perldoc feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

Comment: You can view `use 5.<...>` as specifying which version of the *language* to use. For backwards compatibility reasons, you don't get the latest by default.

Comment: Note that `given` and `when` are experimental and very likely to change.

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, `use warnings;` keeps telling me that.

Comment: It tells you the first part, but not the second. Most experimental stuff does go in unchanged, but that's not going to be the case here. It's definitely a broken design unsuitable for consumption. There was recently an effort to move forward on fixing this, but all it really revealed is that the way forward isn't clear.

Comment: What do you use instead in the meanwhile? `if`/`elsif`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement

```
use VERSION;
```

does an implicit

```
no feature ':all';
use feature ':VERSION';
```

So:

> Why isn't Perl using the features from the latest version installed by default?

According to [`perldoc feature`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html):

> It is usually impossible to add new syntax to Perl without breaking some existing programs. This pragma provides a way to minimize that risk. New syntactic constructs, or new semantic meanings to older constructs, can be enabled by `use feature 'foo'`, and will be parsed only when the appropriate feature pragma is in scope.